# how can i find the sum of all integers given in the string by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I calculate the sum of all the numbers in a string by using the JavaScript ? In the example below, the expected result would be 2+0+1+5. My attempt is below.

```
var a = "weare20boysand15girls";
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        var b = Number(a[i]);
        var c=0;
        c += b;
        console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the question you asked for an expected result of **2015**

the given string is

```
var a = "weare20boysand15girls";
```

the oneliner for this solution:

```
console.log([...a].filter( e => isFinite(e)).join(''));
```

but you marked as correct answer an result of **8**

the oneliner for this solution:

```
console.log([...a].filter( e => isFinite(e)).reduce((a, b)=>parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)));
```

Use regex only when it is impossible to use an other way...

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, but can you please explain it sir ?

Comment: yes i can ...
the `[...a]`convert the string to an array. i `.filter` this array and Check whether a number is  `isFinite`, legal number. the sum function `reduce`must not be explained (?)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to find all the integers. and use reduce function to compute sum

```js
var a = "weare20boysand15girls";

var res = a.replace(/\D+/g, '').split('').reduce((a, b) => {
  return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
});
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
var a = "weare20boysand15girls";
var b = a.match(/(\d)/g).map((a) => parseInt(a)).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the ascii value to identify numerical characters, and then sum it

```js
var sum = 0;
var a = "weare20boysand15girls";
for (var i; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && a.charCodeAt(i) <= 57) {
    sum += a.charCodeAt(i) - 48;
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest regex solution for this. Separate number from your whole string by digits `[0-9]` regex and sum up them using loop.

```js
var a = "weare20boysand15girls";
const regex = /[0-9]/g;
var num = a.match(regex);
var result=0;
num.forEach(function(match){
    result+=parseInt(match);
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
const input = "weare20boysand15girls";
const result =
    // Transform the string to an array.
    input.split("")
    // Use the reduce function to sum only the elements that are numbers.
    .reduce((sum, el) => isNaN(el) ? sum : sum + Number(el), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try this:  You have to split the string to an array and then test each character for addition.

```
function sumNumbers_in_a_String() {

  var strName = "weare20boysand15girls";
  var strArray = strName.split("");
  var c = 0;
  var l = strArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){
      if (parseInt(strArray[i])){
         var b = Number(strArray[i]);
         var c = c + b;
      }
 }
}
```